# Sort List with duplicate keys by custom comparer

Tags: c#, list, sorting, icomparer

I have the `List` `inputColl` of type `MyValue` with many duplicate keys:

```
myValue1.Id=100;
myValue2.Id=100;
...etc
```

And I have custom comparer to compare two `MyValue` elements by `Id`:

```
inputColl.Sort(myValueComparer);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comparer:

```
public class MyValueComparerById : IComparer<MyValue>
{
    public int Compare(MyValue x, MyValue y)
    {
        if (x.Id == y.Id)
            return 0;
        else if (x.Id > y.Id)
            return -1;
        else if (x.Id < y.Id)
            return 1;

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you run and see how it sorts?

Comment: Post the comparer code, also.

Comment: What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: What goes wrong? Without that we can't say what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Unless your equality comparer is not implemented badly, your solution should work.

But I suggest an easier approach, using linq:

```
inputCol = inputCol.OrderBy(o => o.Id).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

You already have an `int` comparer so is better to use it instead of rewriting same logic:

```
public class MyValueComparerById : IComparer<MyValue>
{
    public int Compare(MyValue x, MyValue y)
    {
         return x.Id.CompareTo(y.Id);        
    }
}
```

** Update edit **

For further improvements maybe you might want to consider additional comparison in case of `Id` equality:

```
public class MyValueComparerById : IComparer<MyValue>
{
    public int Compare(MyValue x, MyValue y)
    {
        var firstResult = x.Id.CompareTo(y.Id);        
        if (firstResult == 0)
        {
            // I'm assuming that MyValue has an additional string property named 'SomeName'
            return x.SomeName.CompareTo(y.SomeName);
        }
        return firstResult;
    }
}
```